# Syntax highlighting for .tpl file in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, syntax-highlighting, aptana-studio

I am trying to edit a smarty php template file in Aptana studio 3, and unfortunately it is very very plain, black text on a white background.

I would like to activate syntax highlighting for .tpl files.

I have already tried going to ***Preferences > General > Content types*** and have added ****.tpl*** to the HTML and PHP sections under text, but to no avail.

I am running Mac OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion, any idea how I can get the syntax highlighting to work on the .tpl file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Try  Preferences > General > Content types  add *.tpl to php source in the text dropdown.

Comment: TPL works really well with PHP highlighting... I originally thought HTML would work better.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether *.tpl is included in your associated files.

Go to **Preferences >  General > Editors > File Associations**
Check in the list whether **.tpl* exists, if not add it.

Select *.tpl and if Associated editors is empty click Add and add PHP Source Editor and press OK

Then - as Gabriel Catillo said - go to **Preferences > General > Content Types** and add *.tpl*to PHP Source in the Text dropdown.

*You might need to close and reopen your .tpl files for this to take effect.*